# Prove the correctness of mountain construct algorithm

Tags: python, proof-of-correctness

We are planning to construct a ski resort in a mountain, which has several peaks. In order to make the ski course as long as possible, we decided to make the mountain have exactly one peak by cutting and filling up the mountain. To save the cost of construction, we have to minimize the amount of cutting and filling up. We formulate the problem as follows:

Given a list f of integer elements, make a new list g(of integer elements):

1. sum(f) = sum(g)
2. the elements of g has only one peak; g must monotonically increase until the peak then monotonically decrease.
3. We want to minimize the cost; the cost is given as sum((f[i] - g[i])**2 for i in range(len(f))

Also, to make the problem simple, we exclude inputs that have several maximum peaks, i.e. [3, 6, 5, 6, 2] is not given.

The below code is my solution(which is quite intuitive).
The peak in the solution will be identical with the maximum peak in the given list. Then, while g is not mountain-like(increase then decrease), modify the value of two elements as their average value.

I've checked that the code has returned correct solutions. However, I have problem with proving its correctness.

```py
def solve(f):
    n, idx = len(f), f.index(max(f))
    def isMt(L):
        for i in range(idx):
            if not L[i] <= L[i+1]: return False
        for i in range(idx, len(L)-1):
            if not L[i] >= L[i+1]: return False
        return True
    g = f[:]
    while not isMt(g):
        for i in range(idx):
            if not g[i] <= g[i+1]:
                S = (g[i] + g[i+1])
                g[i], g[i+1] = S // 2, S // 2 + S % 2
        for i in range(idx, n-1):
            if not g[i] >= g[i+1]:
                S = (g[i] + g[i+1])
                g[i], g[i+1] = S // 2 + S % 2, S // 2
    return g
```

Comment: If you wrote a bunch of code with no idea why it should even be correct, there's a good chance it's not. Writing code with no idea why it should even be correct is a really bad way to approach programming.

Comment: In this case, your code *isn't* correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your code *isn't* correct. For example, for the following input:

```
[1, 5, 6, 2, 7]
```

your code produces the following output:

```
[1, 4, 4, 5, 7]
```

despite the existence of a better option:

```
[1, 4, 5, 5, 6]
```

Also, depending on the definition of "monotonic" in use, your mountain's slopes may not actually be monotonically increasing/decreasing.

Comment: First of all, thank you for pointing out the flaws in my code. About the dependence on the definition, I cannot understand why the slopes may not be inc. or dec. (If you mean 'strictly', that is different from monotonically)

Comment: @Arces: "If you mean 'strictly', that is different from monotonically" - that depends on the definition in use.